# Suppose I have a NFD text, how do I recompose it back

Tags: java

Suppose I was given an [NFD (Normalization Form D (Canonical Decomposition))](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Normalization_Forms_Table) text, how would I recompose it back. In other words, if I had `"แก ้ว"`, then I want it recomposed back to `"แก้ว"`. The following java code doesn't do it.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;                                                   // [01]
import java.io.FileReader;                                                       // [02]
import java.io.PrintWriter;                                                      // [03]
import java.text.Normalizer;                                                     // [04]
                                                                                 // [05]
public class RecomposeNFD {                                                      // [06]
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {                    // [07]
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")); // [08]
        PrintWriter    writer = new PrintWriter("output.txt");                   // [09]
        String line = null;                                                      // [10]
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                             // [11]
            String nfd       = Normalizer.normalize(line, Normalizer.Form.NFD);  // [12]
            String recompose = Normalizer.normalize(nfd,  Normalizer.Form.NFC);  // [13]
            writer.println(line + "_" + nfd + "_" + recompose);                  // [14]
        }                                                                        // [15]
        writer.close();                                                          // [16]
        reader.close();                                                          // [17]
    }                                                                            // [18]
}                                                                                // [19]
```

for `input.txt` (UTF-8) of

```
あ
แก้ว
แก ้ว
```

[image]

using the following command

```
javac RecomposeNFD.java
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 RecomposeNFD
```

gives the following output:

| Line | Actual Output | Expected Output | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | あ_あ_あ | あ_あ_あ | As Expected |
| 2 | แก้ว_แก้ว_แก้ว | แก้ว_แก ้ว_แก้ว | Not As Expected (2nd element) |
| 3 | แก ้ว_แก ้ว_แก ้ว | แก ้ว_แก ้ว_แก้ว | Not As Expected (3rd element) |

When I was creating this test code, I found that `Normalizer.normalize(line, Normalizer.Form.NFD);` does not decompose as expected in output of line 3.

Comment: I compared the two [here](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=แก้ว%09แก+้ว). It says you have a space there. I'm not sure if that space is suppose to be removed by normalization. I would think not. Compare that to [two representations of Å](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=Å%09Å) `\u212B` and `\u0041\u030A` that both will result in it's canonical form `\u00C5`. (Note that `\u0009` is the tabular character). If I do the same thing to the last Å adding a space in between `A ̊`, there's [noway](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=A+̊) to turn it into the canonical form.

Comment: I tried your code with the 3 different representations of "Å". The `\u212B`, the `\u0041\u030A` and the `\u00C5` version. They all result in `nfd` equal to `\u0041\u030A` and `recompose` to `\u00C5`.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that while I can reproduce your code, I do not think Java is doing anything wrong. [codepoints](https://codepoints.net/search?q=ก้) says that the symbol/grapheme `ก้` is composed of two codepoints. The `​ ้` is a non-spacing mark :)

Comment: @Scratte: I use [EmEditor](https://www.emeditor.com/) whenever I encounter a non-ASCII language. I did not notice there was a space there (`input.txt`'s `line 3`: `U+0E41 U+0E01 U+0020 U+0E49`). Thank you for pointing it out. I guess I should have noticed it with a dotted circle in my editor as shown in the image. However the I-beam cursor of EmEditor moves as if there is no space (`U+0020`). I should be aware of that when I use EmEditor from now on. For your information, I changed the program's `line 14` from using tab (`U+0009`) as a delimiter to underscore (`U+005F`). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An editor might represent `line 2` of `input.txt` below as if it is 1 character (moving [`←`, `→`] or deleting [`Delete`] by 1 key stroke), but in fact if you look at it in binary there are 2 characters. In this example, there is no **Canonical Composition** form and `line 3` looks as if it is **Canonical Decomposition** because of the space that exist (as pointed out by [Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte)). Furthermore, for some editor, the cursor moves as if there is no space for `line 3`.

line 1: `あ` (U+3042)
line 2: `ก้` (U+0E01 U+0E49)
line 3: `ก  ้` (U+0E01 U+0020 U+0E49)

[image]

With an example that has **Canonical Composition** and **Canonical Decomposition** representation, the code works as expected.

| **Input** Editor | **Input** Unicode | **Output** Editor | **Output** Unicode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Å | U+00C5 | Å_Å_Å | **U+00C5** U+005F **U+0041 U+030A** U+005F **U+00C5** |
| Å | U+0041 U+030A | Å_Å_Å | **U+0041 U+030A** U+005F **U+0041 U+030A** U+005F **U+00C5** |
| Å | U+212B | Å_Å_Å | **U+212B** U+005F **U+0041 U+030A** U+005F **U+00C5** |

So basically, **the code is fine**. Point of advice, **make sure to check the input with a binary editor.**

Thanks [Scratte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12695027/scratte).